# How to make event handler with WPF Datagrid checkbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MappingDataGrid">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Included" Binding="{Binding Path=IsIncluded}"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="From" Binding="{Binding Path=KeyString}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="To" Binding="{Binding Path=ValueString}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

I want to make Datagrid with Checkbox, the binding data is on MainWindow's member and I want to use a checkbox when I checked the box the binded object be changed. However, I tried to find an event and event handler but I cannot find that.

Comment: That is not how it works. When you use binding with a DependencyProperty or with an object that implements INotifyPropertyChanged then the updating of the model happens automatically and you use two way binding then the UI also updates when you update your model.  So basically you need to implement binding correctly and it will work without using explicit "event handlers"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add event handler in the ViewModel

example:

```
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
```

and add the event to the member in the ViewModel

```
        private string isIncluded;
    public string IsIncluded
    {
        get { return isIncluded; }
        set
        {
            isIncluded = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsIncluded");
        }
    }
```

and then in the xmal.cs you need to contact the Binding to the ViewModel

```
public partial class Mapping: Window
{
    private readonly ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();
    public ViewModel ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel ;
    }
}
```

and add in the xmal after the binding the event

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MappingDataGrid">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Included" Binding="{Binding Path=IsIncluded,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="From" Binding="{Binding Path=KeyString}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="To" Binding="{Binding Path=ValueString}"></DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```